# Extract values from JSON sub-arrays

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to populate an array ( $scope.children= [];) with all the children extracted from this array format (JSON data from a GET). Note that  there is no top-level label.

```
[
  {
    "tenant_id": 38,
    "name": "Larry",
    "children": [
      "mike"
    ]
  },
  {
    "tenant_id": 89,
    "name": "Moe",
    "children": [
      "paul"
    ]
  },
  {
    "tenant_id": 95,
    "name": "Laurel",
    "children": null
  },
  {
    "tenant_id": 108,
    "name": "Mark",
    "children": [
      "louise"
    ]

  {
    "tenant_id": 39,
    "name": "Hardy",
    "children": [
      "trevor",
      "alison"
    ]
  }

]
```

Comment: And what are the issues you had when trying?  For example using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: Iterate over the array. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: There should be an "Off topic because of lack of trying"

Comment: @mplungjan: you can always provide a custom close reason :)

Comment: I know but I am not as evil as many here

Comment: But the suggestions there were not angular, hence I did not close as dup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, just use map function to return all the children data

```
//Return all the children 
data = data.map(function(item) {
    return item.children;
})
```

then in your Angular html you can do a nested view

```
<div ng-repeat="chilren in data"> 
    <label ng-repeat="item in chilren">{{item}}</label>
</div>
```

or the fastest way just use the angular ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data"> 
    <label ng-repeat="value in item.children">{{value }}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: That would not process the given JSON

Comment: What framework/JS version are you using?

Comment: I was hoping this would work on the HTML side  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
      <label>{{item.children}}</label>
   
    </div>

Comment: @mplungjan i am using ES6 just now, just change to ES5

Comment: Right, because chrome gave me error on ">". Now we get an array of arrays https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jw2nungy/ - after fixing the JSON

Comment: @user3760188 just updated my answer with angular solution :)

Comment: Thanks Tim...i got lost iterating through nested arrays. "Map" was beyond simple!